React-native app crashes when install react-native-twitter-signin
my react-native app crashes when install react-native-twitter-signin after following guideline given https://github.com/react-native-twitter-signin/twitter-signin#prerequisites.
the output is
ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in dylib built for iOS, file '/Users/beykan/Desktop/react-native-new/AwesomeProject/ios/Pods/TwitterCore/iOS/TwitterCore.framework/TwitterCore' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


2024-05-05 16:55:40.905 xcodebuild[36861:207688] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2F6E33CB-8741-4DC5-A82D-C74E417125DD, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:2F6E33CB-8741-4DC5-A82D-C74E417125DD, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 }
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/beykan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AwesomeProject-dfrwbqswilehisegtuyhoamhwida/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AwesomeProject.app/AwesomeProject normal (in target 'AwesomeProject' from project 'AwesomeProject')
(1 failure)

beykan@alper-MacBook-Air AwesomeProject % 

any solution would be so awesome
